# Extract and name PNG's from loops

Tags: export, files-and-directories, png-format

I want to extract PNG files and name them depending on the dummy variable of a loop. For example, starting from

`Do[Export["image.png", ListPlot[Table[i, {i, k}]]], {k, 1, 2}]`,

I would like to export two files named "image-1.png", "image-2.png" corresponding to `ListPlot[Table[i, {i, 1}]]` and `ListPlot[Table[i, {i, 2}]]`, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
Do[Export["image-" <> ToString[k] <> ".png", ListPlot[Table[i, {i, k}]]], {k, 1, 2}],
```